# How to find h with in a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have this equation in my linear algebra class. I don't understand to how to solve for $h$. I have tried to use row operations but it just seem to get messy. Is there and easier way to solve this problem? Is there a way to put it into the calculator?

Let $a_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 3\\ -1 \end{bmatrix}, a_2= \begin{bmatrix} -7\\ -16\\ 3\end{bmatrix}$ and $b= \begin{bmatrix} 5\\ 0\\ h \end{bmatrix}$. For what value(s) of $h$ is **b** in the plane spanned by $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Comment: What happened when you applied the definition of "spanned by" in the sentence "**b** is in the plane spanned by $a_1$ and $a_2$"? Where did you get stuck after doing that?

Answer (score 2):

That will happen if and only if$$\begin{vmatrix}1&-7&5\\3&-16&0\\-1&3&h\end{vmatrix}=0,$$since that means that $a_1$, $a_2$, and $b$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Do I just run a $reff \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -7 & 5 & 0 \\ 3 & -16 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 3 & h & 0\end{bmatrix}$ ? How would I input the $h$ into the calculator or could I use MATLAB? I know how to solve it the way that JCAA said, but I feel like I'm missing some linear-algebra technique on how to solve it more elegantly.

Comment: What has your comment to do with my answer? What I wrote was that $b\in\operatorname{span}(\{a_1,a_2\})$ if and only if the determinant of a certain matrix is $0$. That determinant is $5h-35$. Therefore, $b\in\operatorname{span}(\{a_1,a_2\})$ if and only if $h=7$.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec b=x\vec a_1+y\vec a_2$ for some $x,y$. So $5=x-7y, 0=3x-16y=3(5+7y)-16y=15+5y, h=-x+3y$, $y=-3, x=-16$. Then $h=7$.